# How to use non mutually exclusive guards in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

I am trying to write a function in Haskell to find how many, of three numbers are larger than the average of said three numbers.

The problem is, I am trying to use guards to increment a "sum", but I'm assuming guards only go to whichever the first condition is that's true. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```hs
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z | aboveAverage x = sum + 1
                          | aboveAverage y = sum + 1
                          | aboveAverage z = sum + 1
                          where
                            aboveAverage a = a > div (x+y+z) 3
                            sum = 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sum up the conditions and convert a `Bool` to an `Int` with [**`fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum):

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z = sum (map (fromEnum . (avg <)) [x, y, z])
    where avg = div (x+y+z) 3
```

or as [@luqui says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199082/how-to-use-non-mutually-exclusive-guards-in-haskell/71199124#comment125853855_71199124) work with `length`:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z = length (filter (avg <) [x, y, z])
    where avg = div (x+y+z) 3
```

Comment: Alternatively `length (filter aboveAverage [x,y,z])`  (though the "summiness" of this is more hidden)

Comment: @luqui I'd say the correctness of the "summy" way is what's hidden, a.o.t. the self-evident correctness of `length ... filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just write it differently, as

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z = aboveAverage x +
                            aboveAverage y +
                            aboveAverage z 
                          where 
                            avg = div (x+y+z) 3
                            aboveAverage a 
                               | a > avg   = 1
                               | otherwise = 0
```

In expression-oriented programming, we do not set and mutate global variables, we arrange for an *expression* to have the same ultimate intended value.

Now you can tweak and simplify. In particular, a less hacky way is

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage x y z = length $
                            aboveAverage x ++
                            aboveAverage y ++
                            aboveAverage z
                          where 
                            avg = div (x+y+z) 3
                            aboveAverage a = [a | a > avg]
                            x & f = f x
```

which translates to a nice list comprehension, as one option.

Or make it more complex and obtuse and less readable if that's your thing.